# Type error "must be string, not datetime.datetime"

Tags: python, django, datetime

I've got some error in my view and I don't have any idea, what is wrong:

```
from datetime import datetime

for month_dict in finished_by_month:
    month_values.append(month_dict['total'])
    month_date = datetime.strptime(month_dict['month'], '%Y-%m-%d')
```

When I try to see my template I've got an error:

> "must be string, not datetime.datetime"

I was looking for solution, but I can't find anything. Maybe someone has got similar problem?

Comment: The code you provided doesn't directly cause the error. You have to provide the rest of the view's code as well as the template's.

Comment: It looks like something is a `datetime.datetime` whe python expects a string.  You haven't posted the full traceback, by I'd guess `month_dict['month']`...

Comment: Searching for ["must be string, not datetime.datetime"](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=must%20be%20string%2C%20not%20datetime.datetime) returns lots of results. Did none of them help?

Comment: @kaja post the remaining code of the view or the value of finished_by_month so we can help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the error is occurring in strptime function, please make sure the value referenced by month_dict['month'] is a string and not in date time format. As you are trying to convert string to time in a particular format, value expected by the compiler is string.

For more details on format of time and additional learning, please visit https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html

Note: Basis of assumption is that only the last line require string format to be provided whereas all above lines will not throw this particular kind of error.